# sshfs - Directories and files not visible after mounting a file system in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, mount, sshfs

I have a very strange situation where all the sub-directories and files of a mounted directory have become invisible from the file manager. I have looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952233/folders-not-visible-in-mounted-drive-but-space-is-occupied) and [here](https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/sshfs-mounts-not-showing-solved/3603), but could not resolve the issue.

Following is the file structure.

**GPU server machine**

```
parent_dir:
    sub_dir1
    sub_dir2
     ...
    sub_dirN
    file1
    file2
     ...
    fileN
```

**Local machine**

```
mnt_dir:
```

The `parent_dir` is mounted at `mnt_dir` using `sshfs`. It all worked fine and all directories were visible from the file manager until yesterday. However, if I mount the directory now, no files or directories are visible.

I have `ssh`ed to the GPU machine and noticed that all sub-directories and files are still available, despite not being shown at `mnt_dir`.

Doing `ctrl+H` at `mnt_dir` would not show anything either.

Strangest thing is, if I copy files or directories from the local machine to `mnt_dir`, they become visible both from file manager and `ssh` terminal.

How should I get the mounted files/directories visible?

(if it helps, I am using TeamViewer to connect to Local machine from home. But I believe this is irrelevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to resolve the issue, again strangely.

1. Unmount the file system using `sudo umount -l /path/to/mnt/mnt_dir`
2. Remove `mnt_dir` using `rm -rf /path/to/mnt/mnt_dir`
3. Recreate `mnt_dir` using `mkdir /path/to/mnt/mnt_dir`
4. mount the file system again to `mnt_dir`

Now, all files and directories will be visible from file manager.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Any idea why re-creating the directory made it work?

Comment: Glad it helped. Honestly idk why and didn't bother to check.

Comment: For me it was a permission issue. I bet permissions changed when recreating the folder. First time under sudo and then under the user.